# How to debug an Azure cloud service on a local machine using Emulator Express

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-cloud-services

I have been able to run Azure cloud services locally before, but Emulator Express is not available anymore.

The same problem appears on two Windows computers.

How to reproduce:

1. Download https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Azure-Cloud-Service-e01df2e4 and unzip it.
2. Open the project in Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.6
3. Follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-emulator-express-debug-run?view=vs-2017 to verify that IIS Express and Emulator Express are selected
4. Try to run the Azure Could Service in Emulator Express.

In step 4, I only have this option in the toolbar:
[image: Toolbar]

If I use that, my Frontend role starts, but the Worker Role does not start.

The same problem exists for one of my own Cloud Service projects.

Installed products in Visual Studio: https://gist.github.com/mfalkvidd/78114c37e16d793c26a44431dad2795d

Comment: That example is 4 years old so it might no longer work. Have you tried just creating a new cloud service and adding a web role and worker role manually in Visual studio?

Comment: Yes. My own cloud service project (created about a month ago) has the same problem.

Comment: Can you provide details about the cloud service so I can repro? C#, Javascript, TypeScript, etc also are you running a web api, web forms, etc I tried it with a simple C# cloud service and added a web and worker role. I have the same opetions as you do the workrole is reporting back as working. Might also want to make sure you Visual Studio is fully updated

Comment: How do I make sure my Visual Studio is fully updated, except having v15.9.6?

Comment: I created a new project (C# cloud service), and that project can indeed be started in Emulator Express. So the problem seems to be related to my project.

Comment: You can check the latest version by opening up VS -> Help -> Check for updates. And hearing you can run the other project at least helps narrow it down to likely not an issue with your VS. Any error messages or other info you could share when you try to run your project that might help us debug further?

Comment: Any update? Can you please share the details as asked in the comment above?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
The project I has created was created from the VS guide for Cloud Services, where I opted to create a Frontend.Web and a WorkerRole, but I never used the Frontend.Web. I deleted the Frontend.Web project and that made it possible to start the worker role in Emulator Express.